# Convert real numbers to binary and vice versa (in Python)

Tags: python, binary, combinations

Consider a real number `x.y`. How can `x.y` be converted into its binary representation with `m` digits in the whole number and `n` digits in the fraction, using a Python function?

> e.g., assume `x.y=10.625`, `m=6`, and `n=5`; then the binary representation
>   should be, `00101010100` where the first five rightmost bits represent the fraction
>   `(0.625)`, and the leftmost six bits represent the whole number `(10)`.

Now, how can a Python function be written to convert `00101010100` to its base `10` representation (that is `10.625`) given `m` and `n` as the parameters along with the binary number?

Edited: (Definition of `m` and `n`)

`m` and `n` can be any positive integer. `(m+n)` is the full length of the binary string that will be generated by the function given that the number converted is a positive value.

Comment: Check [this](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/) library.

Comment: Your question is not clear, since you do not specify just how you get the number (such as `10.625`). Is it already stored as a float value in a Python variable, is it stored with the integer part as an integer in variable `x` and fractional part as a float value in variable `y`, or something else? This matters for the solution I have in mind. What are the limits on `m` and `n`? Also, what work have you done on this problem so far, and just where are you stuck? Please show us that you are not just dumping a  homework problem on us.

Comment: @LevZakharov Thanks

Comment: @RoryDaulton  I'm actually trying to convert the matlab answer provided at https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25549-convert-floating-point-to-binary into a Python function which takes three inputs e.g., func(10.625, 6,5). As the answer it should return the string=> "00101010100".

Comment: I'll accept that comment as answers to my questions, though you did not give limits for `m` and `n`. If you edit that information into your question I can retract my downvote.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that does what you want. These functions do no error-checking and could be off for large values of `m + n`, say beyond `53` since the standard float variable holds only 53 significant binary digits. Some tricks not shown here could be done for larger values of `m + n`.

```
def float_to_binary(x, m, n):
    """Convert the float value `x` to a binary string of length `m + n`
    where the first `m` binary digits are the integer part and the last
    'n' binary digits are the fractional part of `x`.
    """
    x_scaled = round(x * 2 ** n)
    return '{:0{}b}'.format(x_scaled, m + n)

def binary_to_float(bstr, m, n):
    """Convert a binary string in the format given above to its float
    value.
    """
    return int(bstr, 2) / 2 ** n

print(float_to_binary(10.625, 6, 5))
print(binary_to_float('00101010100', 6, 5))
```

The printout from that is what you wanted:

```
00101010100
10.625
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Binary fractions](https://pypi.org/project/binary-fractions/) package. With this package you can convert binary-fraction strings into floats and vice-versa.

Example:

```
>>> from binary_fractions import Binary
>>> str(Binary(10.625))
'0b1010.101'
>>> float(Binary("1010.101"))
10.625
```

It has many more helper functions to manipulate binary strings such as: shift, add, fill, to_exponential, invert...

PS: Shameless plug, I'm the author of this package.